# CSS - align-self issue

Tags: html, css

How can I move yellow item to right?

1. `float` have no effect
2. `align-self` does not work

[image: Result]

HTML

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex {
    background: green;
    display: flex;
}

.flex .item:first-child {
    background: red;
}

.flex .item:last-child {
    background: yellow;
}
```

1. https://jsfiddle.net/cd6j4y13/
2. https://jsfiddle.net/cd6j4y13/embedded/result/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right-aligning flex item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429003/right-aligning-flex-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
.flex {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cd6j4y13/5/

Answer (score 4):

You can add margin-left:auto to `.flex .item:last-child`

```
.flex {
    background: green;
    display: flex;
}

.flex .item:first-child {
    background: red;
}

.flex .item:last-child {
    background: yellow;
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cd6j4y13/1/

Comment: This solution creates two rows whereas I think the original question desires a single row (of green) EDIT* I was on safari*

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/cd6j4y13/2/

`float:left` to first child

`float:right` to last child

`overflow:auto` to parent

Seems to do the trick.

Edit* The above works only on safari, as the other answer points out adding margin-left:auto to last:child works elsewhere

https://jsfiddle.net/cd6j4y13/4/

Comment: This solution works on safari not on chrome, the solution above this seems to work on chrome but not on safari..

Comment: Merging our answers works on both browsers, edited in

Comment: Are you sure there is not an easier way?