# flexbox - align to the right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I achieve get some element to the very end of the flexbox div?

[image]

```
#wrap {
    display: flex;
}
.right {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Here is codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMEgJO

Comment: Note that `align-self` moves flex items along the *cross axis*, which would be vertical in your case (`flex-direction: row`). So `align-self: flex-end` would move the item down, not right. Since you're trying to align the item to the right on the *main axis*, here are some options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right-aligning flex item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429003/right-aligning-flex-item)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.right {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}`

**margin-left:auto**
should do it