# Table-cell element's not accepting max-width value

Tags: css

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253299/871404) I tried to vertically center my `header` elements, however I'm having trouble since there's a `container` element in between that makes sure they're contained within a certain `max-width` and centered. I applied `display: table-cell` to this element and now its `max-width` doesn't work (occupies the whole screen width regardless of its `max-width`). How to solve this problem?

Markup:

```
<header class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="header__branding" href="<?php bloginfo( "wpurl" ); ?>">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo( "template_url" ); ?>/dist/images/baia_logo.svg" />
    </a> 
    <nav class="nav_primary">
      <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'main menu' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: url(../images/header.jpg) 50% 50% repeat-x;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}    
.header__branding {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 52px;
    display: block;
}
.nav_primary {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: So you want `container` and all of it contents centered inside `header`. Regardless of what is inside `container`?

Comment: Yes I want "container" to be centered within "header".

Comment: To clarify, you want:
1. A header, which has a background that covers the whole width of a screen.
2. A container inside that header which is centered and max 1500px wide.
3. A logo on the left and navigation on the right side of said container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is an answer to your question exactly. I will leave the old one as an alternative.**

### The problem

From [CSS 2.2 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#min-max-widths):

> In CSS 2.2, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, **table cells**, table columns, and column groups is undefined.

So it seems there is no way of adding a max-width to a `table-cell` currently. You could add a `table-cell` to each side of the `container` and set a 1500px width to the `container` with `media queries` but this isn't preferred as there is a workaround.

---

### A solution

If you want to limit the width of the nav provided in your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253299/5047630) to 1500px you can add a `container` like you did but the block structure should be a little different.

**Now you have:**

- `banner` as a table
- `container` as a table-cell
- `header_branding` and `nav_primary` as blocks inside the cell

**Consider changin the structure to following:**

- `banner` to a block
- `container` to a table
- `header_branding` and `nav_primary` to table-cells

The `banner` is only a 100% wide background element.

Then give the `container` a `max-width` of 1500px like you did but remember to give it a 100% `width` also. Otherwize it wont try to expand to the whole width of the screen as **it doesn't have to** but now the `max-width` will be a limiting factor.

[Here](http://codepen.io/V-Kopio/pen/bZjmgP) is a CodePen example provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253299/5047630) but with a container limiting the width to 1500px.

**Your example modified:**

```css
.banner {
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
}

.header_branding, .nav_primary {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}

.header_branding {
    width: 150px;
    height: 52px;
}

.nav_primary {
    text-align: right;
}

/* To make edges visible for the demo */
.banner, .container, .header_branding, .nav_primary { 
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<header class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="header_branding" href="">
      <img src="" />
    </a>
    
    <nav class="nav_primary">
      [Menu items]
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks! But you didn't really address the problem as presented in the question, which was to vertically center the "container" element itself. Instead, you center its content within "container". So in my case I would set a fixed height to "container" equal to the fixed height of "banner" element right? That's my understanding of your answer, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Basically the header element is just a wrapper to give you a 100% width background at all times. The container element is your table with the vertically centered content which is limited to 1500px max-width. I can update this answer to include your code modified to make it more understandable.

Comment: The answer is now modified, hope it answers the question better.

Comment: Now the text itself should also be more clear. I admit, it was a bit confusign.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `height` or `max-height` for `.container` then use `flex` on `header`:

```
.banner {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/theblindprophet/pen/NAzAWj

*This will not work for some versions of IE, check [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for details.*

---

With `display: inline-block`:

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
    text-align: center;

/* May want to do this if there is risk the container may be narrower than the element inside */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 300px;
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/theblindprophet/pen/XKYKdy

Reference: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

Comment: Thanks, but if you change the "max-width" value of "container" to say, 1500px, it doesn't work ("container" still doesn't visually get a width of 1500px)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

property is what you are looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to vertically align elements inside the `container` it to use `line-height` as you know the height of your `header`. The downside of this is that you cannot have more than one row of text but usually this is the intent in the first place.

I tried to strip your code to the minimum and made a working demo [here](http://codepen.io/V-Kopio/pen/qNymAx?editors=1100).

Basically if the container is 160px tall you can add `line-height` of 160px for the menu items to vertically align them to the middle.

To vertically align your image, I used the accepted method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div) question.

To future proof, here is the code used in my demo:

```css
* {
    margin: 0; /* Illustrative */
    padding: 0; /* Illustrative */
}

.banner {
 background: #222; /* Illustrative */
 width: 100%;
}
.container {
 background: #aaa; /* Illustrative */
 max-width: 800px; /* Change to desired value */
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}    
.header__branding {
 background: #555; /* Illustrative */
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 height: 160px;
 display: block;
}

.header__branding span {
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 160px;
}

.nav_primary {
 float: right;
}

.nav_primary a {
    line-height: 160px;
}

img {
    background: #3867EA; /* Illustrative */
    width: 100px; /* Illustrative */
    height: 100px; /* Illustrative */
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header class="banner">
  <div class="container">
 <a class="header__branding" href="#">
   <img alt="Logo" /><span>Title</span>
 </a>
 
 <nav class="nav_primary">
   <a>Menu1</a> <a>Menu2</a> <a>Menu3</a>
 </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```