# Align multiple flex items as if they were floated right

Tags: html, css, css-float, flexbox

I am trying to achieve the equivalent of floats with Flexbox.

I'm succeeding if there is only one element pushed to the right, but failing when there are multiple elements that need to be floated right, unless worked around with the general sibling selector (`~`).

**Attempt #1:**

Failing as the red block should be on the right

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  margin: -5px;
}
.block__element {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.block__element--first {
  order: -1;
}
.block__element--right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.u-error {
  background: #ce0e0e;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__element">random elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--right u-error">right elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--first">first elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--right">right elem</div>
</div>
```

**Attempt #2:**

Uses the general sibling selector (`~`) so relies on markup order, will not work if the order is modified using `order`.

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  margin: -5px;
}
.block__element {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.block__element--first {
  order: -1;
}
.block__element--right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.u-error {
  background: #ce0e0e;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__element">random elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--right u-error">right elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--first">first elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--right">right elem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite sure either. [But shouldn't you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429003/right-aligning-flex-item) just be able to use a `margin-left: auto` on the first element you want to "float"?    EDIT: just confirmed, yes you can

Comment: @vladdobra yes, this is what i'm doing already, but I do not know which one is the first element (markup is dynamic), which was covered with my attempt #2

Comment: @veksen I'm confused, did you use the `~` selector? It does work if you use it like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/hnzfe37x/)

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz not when combined with `order`: https://jsfiddle.net/hnzfe37x/1/

Comment: @veksen Then you should do what Michael suggested. Be aware of the accessibility issues using `order` brings into the table.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz it's working as intended, as `~` selects the next sibling elements, but the "starting" selector was reordered.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key is **not** to use `margin-left: auto` on the items you want positioned to the right. As you can see, that spaces them away from each other.

Instead, use `margin-right: auto` on the right-most item of the left section. That will push everything else to the right.

```css
.block > div:first-child { margin-right: auto; }
/* The actual left-section right-most item has order:-1, so the selector above
   ends up targeting the proper item. */

.block {
  display: flex;
  margin: -5px;
}
.block__element {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.block__element--first {
  order: -1;
}
.block__element--right {} .u-error {
  background: #ce0e0e;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__element">random elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--right u-error">right elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--first">first elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--right">right elem</div>
</div>
```

**Another option** to consider would be to use a pseudo-element that inserts an invisible flex item between the left and right sections, giving this item `flex: 1`.

```css
.block::after {
  content: "spacer element";
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  flex: 1;
  visibility: hidden; /* disable this rule to see the item at work */
}
.block {
  display: flex;
  margin: -5px;
}
.block__element {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.block__element--first {
  order: -1;
}
.block__element--right {
  order: 2;
}
.u-error {
  background: #ce0e0e;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__element">random elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--right u-error">right elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--first">first elem</div>
  <div class="block__element block__element--right">right elem</div>
</div>
```