# How to horizontally align divs while aligning one to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align an input text and all the buttons you see in the following image to the bottom of "My text".

The bottom should be the bottom of the M not the bottom of the y. 
**Edit**: as a second choice, all the elements can be aligned to the vertical center of `my text'.

Buttons 3 and 4 have to be aligned to the right.

[image]

If there isn't enough space, `My text` should remain on the first line, and the rest should go into a new line.

I tried using `float: right` with no luck, because button 3 and 4 go to the right upper edge. I tried displaying them inline, but that way they are not aligned on the right. I don't know what else to try.

My current code is the following, which gives me bottom alignment with Firefox but not with Chrome (as you can see, buttons 3 and 4 are not aligned with buttons 1 and 2)

I hope someone can help me.

```css
div.inline { 
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
   
<div id="titleBar">
<div class="inline" style="position: relative; width: 100%;">
 <div class="inline" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 2em; color: #D00000;">My text</div>
 <div class="inline">
  <form>
   <div class="inline">
    <input type="text" style="width: 16em" value="input text">&nbsp;
   </div>
   <div class="inline">
    <input type="submit" value="button 1"></input>
    <button>button 2</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>

 <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;">
  <button >button 3</button>
  <button >button 4</button>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox can line them up. Check out the Answer to this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429003/how-to-right-align-flex-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429003/how-to-right-align-flex-item)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I had found another solution with flexbox that didn't work. I'm using now `display: flex; align-items: center; ` to vertically align the items. I hope flexbox is supported by mobile devices too