# How to align text to middle of the input filed?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to align my text in the `span tag` to center of the `input field`. But when i used the `"text-align": center` in my css, it is not working.

When i changed the `span tag` to `paragraph tag` my `input field` become big.

the code:

```
<div class="nxui-form-group">
    <label for="external-realisation">
      <img src="assets/images/purchase_order.svg" class="nxui-icon-small nxui-icon-align-bottom">
      {{ 'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.external-realisation' | translate }}
    </label>
    <div *ngIf="!isExternal">
      {{ 'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.without-order' | translate }}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="isExternal" class="nxui-label-plus-field">
      <span class="nxui-non-breakable-label">{{ 'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.with-order' | translate }}&nbsp;</span>
      <input [nxuiPlaceholder]="'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.external-realisation' | translate"
             [title]="'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.external-realisation' | translate"
             class="nxui-form-control"
             formControlName="company"
             id="external-realisation"
             pInputText
             >
    </div>
  </div>
```

It looks like this when i added the `paragraph tag`: 
[image]

With `span tag`:
[image]

Answer to my question:

```
.nxui-label-plus-field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nxui-non-breakable-label {
  white-space:nowrap ;
}
```

highly appreciated for the inputs.

Thanks

Comment: <input type="text" style="text-align:right;"/>  try this

Comment: if you use the text-align css property but it doesn't come through, something else is blocking it. It should be all you need. F12 through your page's css and find out why it isn't taking.

Comment: Do you mean center or middle? Those are different things!

Comment: @TheParam it aligns the text inside the input field, i need the text outside the field.

Comment: @MrLister, i need it center of the input field.

Comment: @PraveenkumarBeedanal As per your question, I think your expectation is span should be vertically middle of input field right ? Basically, your expectation of alignment should be similar to p tag right ?

Comment: @SheebanSingaram yes, exactly

Comment: @PraveenkumarBeedanal okay! you can use display flex/grid properties, in your parent class "nxui-label-plus-field" and align the items center. Let me know you need code snippet, I will post the answer.

Comment: @SheebanSingaram it would be great, if you post tge snippet.

Comment: Will do! mean time take a look of this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429003/how-to-right-align-flex-item it would be helpful to slove your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188756/discussion-between-sheeban-singaram-and-praveenkumar-beedanal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngIf="isExternal" class="nxui-label-plus-field">
  <span class="nxui-non-breakable-label">{{ 'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.with-order' | translate }}&nbsp;</span>
  <input [nxuiPlaceholder]="'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.external-realisation' | translate"
         [title]="'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.external-realisation' | translate"
         class="nxui-form-control"
         formControlName="company"
         id="external-realisation"
         pInputText
         >
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
   .nxui-label-plus-field { 
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this  style="text-align:center" to you input element to be like that

```
 <input [nxuiPlaceholder]="'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.external-realisation' | translate"
             [title]="'i18n.all-damage-reports.label.external-realisation' | translate"
             class="nxui-form-control"
             formControlName="company"
             id="external-realisation"
             pInputText
             style="text-align:center"
             >
```