# How to make flex item as left and right in single flex container

Tags: css

I have used flex container in my application with the help of below link.I would like to make flex item as left and right side with below image format.please help how to do this.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429003/how-to-right-align-flex-item)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k497a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each item you want to move it to right you could use property:

```
margin-left: auto;
```

Then it will move to right as your image

Comment: actually,i woud like to make two flex item (left flex item and right flex item)in single container.see the attached image for your reference

Comment: I made a demo for you https://codepen.io/huykon225/pen/vYJmrQV